# Defining Meteor collections when using coffeescript; ReferenceError saying that collection not defined

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, meteor

I am using coffeescript. I have read on the web that when using coffeescript with Meteor, the global variables, such as collections, 
should be defined using @. I have done this but I am still getting the following error. The code from relevant files appears after the error. How can I fix this error?

Thank you.

**Error
--------**

```
ReferenceError: GameStatus is not defined
    at app/server/methods/adminMethods.coffee.js:10:5
```

**----------------------------------
collections/gamestatus.coffee
----------------------------------**

```
@GameStatus = new Meteor.Collection('gamestatus')
```

**----------------------------------
server/adminMethods.coffee
----------------------------------**

```
Meteor.methods
    initializeGameStatus: () ->
        GameStatus.insert({gameOnOff: 0, asymmetric: 0})


if GameStatus.find({}).count() is 0
    Meteor.call 'initializeGameStatus', (err, result) ->
        if err
            console.log(err)
        else
            'GameStatus collection initialized'
```

Comment: why are you defining new Meteor.Collection ? It is new Mongo.Collection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the global scope it could also be the file loading order. To ensure your collections are loaded first move your `collections` directory into a `/lib` directory

Comment: Hi, I have moved my collections folder into the lib folder, but still get the error that it is undefined. Anything else that needs to be considered in this case?

Comment: @batjko Did you change the scope too? `@` if you're on coffeescript and removing `var` if you're on javascript.

Comment: I just noticed I did forget the `@`, yes. Why this is necessary isn't clear to me though. Why does coffeescript require a global variable to be bound to anything?